# failing to pass the variable correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ive been researching for over a week now to get this working.  I know very little about jquery and even reached out to some friends of mine in the IT community but no one has been able to help me thus far.  I'm basically self taught, so if the coding looks all wonky, I apologize.  Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

I have a repeating form(shown below) within a jquery accordian.  I just want the ajax to submit the correct data and keep the current cell from closing so that the user doesn't have to reopen it each time they hit a button.

```
function dg1(dgr, v1, v2, v3) {
   var MM_update = document.getElementById(v1);
   var id = document.getElementById(v2);
   var green_disable = document.getElementById(v3); 

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'disable.php',
   data: { MM_update: MM_update.value, id: id.value, green_disable: green_disable.value    
   },
  dataType: "html", 
  success: function(html){  var foo = dgr.id; $('#' + foo).html(html);          
     document.getElementById('submitDisGreen').disabled = true;   }
  }); 
}
```

This is the repeating form.

```
<form name="disable" method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" id="submitDisGreen" value="Disable" <?php if ($row_Recordset1['green_disable'] != NULL) echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";?> onClick="dg1('dgr<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>', 'MM_update<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>', 'id<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>', 'green_disable<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>'); return false;"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" id="MM_update<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>" value="disableGreen" />
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="green_disable" id="green_disable<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $row_Recordset2['last_name']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does the cell close when the user clicks on the `submitDisGreen` input?

Comment: nope, the cell stays open.

Comment: So when you click on the button the ajax call is made and the Accordion tab is closed after this?

Comment: Currently the accordian tab stays open as it should.  The problem is, as far as I can tell, that the information is not being passed correctly from the form to the function.

Comment: Have you tried printing the arguments of the `dg1` function in the console to know for sure if the arguments are passed to the function?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Aliou, so the form is sending to the function correctly.  I'm a jquery noob, so I used the alert feature to test.  So tried to test the document.getElementById by doing alert(MM_update); and it came back with [objectHTMLinputElement], is that normal?  was hoping it would say disableGreen.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys!  I actually have it working, I just need to get the button to disable after a successful update.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the finished product.  Feels nice to finally have this up and working.  Thanks all.

```
function dg1(dgr, v1, v2, v3, v4) {
var MM_update = document.getElementById(v1).value;
var id = document.getElementById(v2).value;
var green_disable = document.getElementById(v3).value;          
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'disable.php',
data: { MM_update: MM_update, id: id, green_disable: green_disable },
dataType: "html", 
success: function(html){     var foo = dgr; $('#' + foo).html(html);  $('#' + v4).attr("disabled","disabled");   }
}); 
}
```